# Angularjs URL Forward bumps to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to forward to a new url once a form submission completes. Everything works fine, and the forwarding works with the code i'm using, however the view of the window bumps to the bottom of the page. I think it's because the form is quite long and instead of redrawing the page, it is replacing the content. I've tried adding a hash at the end of the forwarding url, and have attempted a few other ways with no luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my promise code:

```
    .then(function(data){
        notify('Success!');
        window.location.replace( BASE_PATH + '#/create/challenge/' + data.response.content.challenge.challenge_id );
    })
```

Comment: for sure would be better to use angular `$window` or event better `$location`.

Comment: is it possible to create a plunkr with your issue?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I would, but I don't think plunkr would be able to duplicate a route change?